# Explanation of unpredictable behaviour of tee

Tags: bash, io-redirection, tee

I encountered a behaviour that I don't understand while testing a script that sums the outputs from repeated executions of a program. To reproduce it create the text files `out`, which represents the output of my program, and `sum`, the file that holds the sum of the values returned on previous executions and which starts out as a copy of `out`,

```
cat > out << EOF
2 20
5 50
EOF
cp out sum
```

The strange thing happens on running

```
paste out sum | awk '{$1 += $3; $2 += $4; NF = 2; print}' | tee sum
```

several times (15-20 times might be needed). Each time it runs, this command should add to the values in `sum` the corresponding values in `out` and write the results back to `sum`. What I get is that it works an unpredictable number of times, then `sum` reverts back to

```
2 20
5 50
```

I have later learned that [I cannot redirect or tee output to the same file I'm working on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696842/how-can-i-use-a-file-in-a-command-and-redirect-output-to-the-same-file-without-t) and solved the issue using a temporary file, still, this behaviour baffles me:

- why does `… | tee sum` work at all (even if only for a limited number of iterations), while `… > sum` never overwrites `sum`?
- why doesn't it work a predictable number of times?

Comment: "while … > sum never overwrites sum" -- can you elaborate on that? What command, exactly, never overwrites `sum`?

Comment: `paste out sum | awk '{$1 += $3; $2 += $4; NF = 2; print}' > sum`. If you try that and then `cat sum`, you should see that `sum` has not changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This,

```
paste out sum | awk ... | tee sum
```

has a race condition. `paste` opens `sum` to read it, and `tee` opens it for writing, truncating it. The shell starts both at approximately the same time, so it's up to chance which one gets to open the file first.

Of course in practice, the shell has to start the utilities one at a time, in some particular order. It probably does that from left to right, so `paste` might have a better chance of going first, but that's an implementation detail, and in any case the OS scheduler decides what runs when.

If `paste` gets to go first, it opens the file with the data still intact, and probably has enough time to read the data too. If `tee` gets to open the file before `paste` has read it, then `paste` sees an empty file instead.

Here,

```
paste out sum | awk ... > sum
```

The shell opens `sum` for writing, truncating it. It might do that in parallel to starting `paste`, but since truncating `sum` doesn't involve starting another utility, it probably happens first. (I'm not exactly sure if there's a rule about the order of processing redirections and starting the commands in a pipeline like this, but I wouldn't count on it.)

There's a tool called `sponge` to fix this issue (and a dozen [questions about it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=sponge)). It collects the input it gets and only writes it after the input is closed. This should have `sum` updated correctly, always:

```
paste out sum | awk ... | sponge sum
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks! By the way, I guess with "If `sum` gets to open the file before `paste`" you really meant "If `tee` gets to open..."